# Spring Boot WS application cannot load external property

Tags: spring-boot, spring-ws

In my Spring-Boot Web Service application, I want to load a property named **appName** with value defined in application.properties.

```
@Endpoint
public class RasEndpoint {

private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://www.mycompany.com/schema/ras/ras-request/V1";

@Value("${appName}")
private String appName;

@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "getProductRequest")
@ResponsePayload
public GetProductResponse getProduct(@RequestPayload GetProductRequest request) {

    System.out.println("appName: " + appName);
    GetProductResponse response = generateStubbedOkResponse();
    return response;
}
```

application.properties has the following entry

```
appName=ras-otc
```

I get the application started via the main Application class as shown below

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

However, when I run the app, I get the following error

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve
>   placeholder 'appName' in string value "${appName}"

Do you guys know what I'm doing wrong?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Hard to say. If I had to guess I would say probably either your properties file is not on the classpath (IDE refresh maybe), or you aren't really starting your app with that main method.

Comment: Hi Dave, it's a very valid point and you made me think in the right direction. While Eclipse IDE had src/main/resources added to the class path but had an exclusion for *.properties and that was causing the issue. Now it's all fixed. Many thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

As Dave mentioned in the comment above, the properties file was not loaded into the classpath. 
The properties file was located in /src/main/resources folder, which was added to source, under build path in Eclipse IDE, however had an exclusion rule applied which prevented the properties file from being loaded into the classpath. By removing the exclusion, I was able to load the properties correctly.